# mathjax conflict with jquery-popbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mathjax

I use mathjax on my website and I found that when using jquery-popbox, the mathjax text is on top of the popbox. I created a jsfiddle which shows this problem

https://jsfiddle.net/of5g5f32/

I use mathjax with Latex notation

```
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">        
 MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$']]}});
 </script>
```

the question is, how can I enforce the popbox on top of the mathjax symbols?

thanks 
carl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution would be to set `z-index` on your `.box` element, but after the `popbox` has been assigned. Like this:

```
$('.popbox').popbox();
$('.box').css('z-index','1');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7tggay6z/